# wp_list_comments give first and last name

Tags: wordpress, comments

I am using this standard function to displayy comments on a website running Wordpress 4.0:

```
wp_list_comments();
```

However, that way comments by registered users are shown with their username instead of their **first and last name**. This is obviously also a security risk.

Anyway to influence this function to give our first and last names or do I have to do a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress will always list the preferred Display Name your users can set in their profile settings. Just have them set it to their preferred name there and you are good to go.